# Create a Stdout and stderr files with multiple commands and compress the output

Tags: python, bash, stdout, stderr

Since I have many commands in a bash script I would like to use the following formula to get stdout and stderr files:

```
{
...
commands
...
} 2>stderr.txt >stdout.txt
```

However my code is a little bit more complicated than that.

- Firstly, the bash file is run using `session = Popen(['/home/claudio/programs/instruction.sh', variable1, variable2], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)`
- Then because within the 'commands' reference, a variable ($folder) is created and it is useful to find the correct pathway for the final archive compression.

Since the sderr and the stdout files must be stored within the final compress folder I thought that the final code could sound something like that

```
#!bin/bash

variable1=$1
variable2=$2
folder=$variable1$variable2

{
...
commands
...
folder=$variable1$variable2
path=/home/claudio/test/$folder/final/proof
mv *.jpeg $path
...
} 2>/home/claudio/test/$folder/final/proof/stderr.txt >/home/claudio/test/$folder/final/proof/stdout.txt

cd /home/claudio/test/ && tar -zcf $folder.tar.gz $folder
mv $folder.tar.gz '/home/claudio/newfiles/'
```

However it does not work and despite the files would be correctly created, the instructions within the brackets are not read.

Is there an easy way to solve this issue using bash or python as well?

Thank you

EDIT:
As required I forward here a brief example:

```
#!bin/bash

start=$1
name=$2
folder=$start$name

{
start=$1
name=$2
folder=$start$name
mkdir /home/claudio/Scrivania/$folder
echo $PWD
echo "sounds good"

} 2>/home/claudio/Scrivania/$folder/stderr.txt >/home/claudio/Scrivania/$folder/stdout.txt

cd /home/claudio/Scrivania
tar -zcf $folder.tar.gz $folder
```

output:

```
 line 15: /home/claudio/Scrivania/23421claudio/stderr.txt Not existing file or directory
```

Comment: This code would do what you want (modulo bugs like `cd /home/claudio/test/ tar -zcf ..`), so the problem is something else. The best way to ensure that your question accurately captures the problem is to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: please check your code for syntax issues at https://shellcheck.net and then update your Q with cleaned up code. Good luck.

Comment: And agree about MCVE, but as that is rather general description, I'd reccomend that you read, review and take to heart the items on this page : [bash info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) . Search for "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Comment: I don't see any `mkdir` commands so wondering if you've verified elsewhere that all of the sub-directories actually exist? is the `stderr.txt` file created and if so is there anything in the file that might indicate issues/errors with the commands (inside the braces)?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> {
>      mkdir /home/claudio/Scrivania/$folder
> } 2>/home/claudio/Scrivania/$folder/stderr.txt
> ```

I think the error is clear - there is no such path when creating the redirection. You seem to be creating the directory *after* creating the redirection. First create the directory, so it exists, then redirect stuff to a file inside it. A redirection will not automatically create the path to a file. [Tested on repl](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/ShowyCloseProject).

```
mkdir ./"$folder" # yay create the folder
{
    stuff...
} 2>./"$folder"/stderr.txt # redirect to a file inside _existing_ folder
```